# How to solve keyboard key setting in the remote server (remote desktop)

Tags: linux, keyboard, remote-desktop

I am using remote desktop to connect to my Linux server. But the keys from my local laptop is not reflecting in my remote server. Especially, it is getting very difficult to type characters such as *,^,(),[],,/,',:,** etc. What I see and type in my local laptop does not reflect in the result on the remote desktop. Could you please help me to solve the issue?

How to make the keyboard keys layout setting the same as the local keyboard.

Thanks!

Comment: You might have different locales (*i.e., language and keyboard layout) on the two machines. There may also be a setting in the remote desktop application to adjust locale.

Comment: Thanks! You are right. I tried that and it is working now. I tried to adjust the keyboard layout setting on my remote desktop many times but never checked it with the local system. Thanks again.